# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) (This is for candy machine on solana)

Tags: javascript

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

After running this.

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \
    -e mainnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/hashlips-mainnet.json \
    -cp config.json \
    -c example \
    ./assets
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: The argument of `JSON.parse` is the empty string.

Comment: so is there something missing i should add after -cp config.json?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have wrong JSON object, it may contain symbols like: "`" or something else. Here you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse